# Metro bundler not starting after successful build. gives unable to load script error

Tags: react-native

My code compiles fine but when it reaches to metro bundler loading the js bundle it gives this error I tried many solutions: TCP reverse, changing debug IP, the manual bundle generator command
no luck.

Getting this error :

`Unable to load script. Make sure you re either running a metro server or that your bundle index.android.bundle is packaged correctly for release`

Comment: Can you please add also the error which bundler is throwing?

Comment: Unable to load script. Make sure you re either running a metro server or that your bundle index.android.bundle is packaged correctly for release

Answer (score -1):

You have to run bundler too.

If you run

```
react-native run-android
```

it will start the bundler and then install and run app.

You can also start it seperately using `react-native start` which can be usually referenced using  `npm start` or `yarn start`

Comment: this is not the solution i am afraid because I ran a mock project with the same version it runs fine